# Is it safe to give ownership of files to "daemon"?

Tags: php, apache, unix, drupal

I was having trouble uploading files using my CMS (drupal). When I put more restrictive file permissions on, I could not upload anything. Then I changed the owner of the upload directory and all sub-folders to "daemon," and everything worked fine. What exactly is "daemon?" Is this the user used by apache or PHP?

Is it safe to use daemon as the owner for folders and sub-folders in an upload directory?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/835796/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-daemon-group-and-user-on-rhel-centos-linux

Comment: that doesn't answer the question "is it safe to use as ownership on upload directories?"

Comment: You should ask that on [SuperUser](//superuser.com) or [Server Fault](//serverfault.com) then, as it's not about programming but server administration

Comment: i did, no one answered: https://serverfault.com/questions/857950/is-it-safe-to-give-ownership-of-files-to-daemon